# Deleted Google Play Settings... Help!

Tags: google-play-store

I was trying to make room on my cell which is a Huawei Ascend Y215 and I deleted Google Play Settings, Now my Google Play won't work. Please help!

Comment: "won't work": What actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on this website to reinstall Google Play on your phone.

http://www.androidauthority.com/install-google-play-store-312812/

Answer (score 0):

There might be a possibility that you just disabled google play settings.
To check just go into settings>apps>all and search for play settings .
If it exists click on it and enable it :) !